# I need to create a dropdown in an HTML form that lists the next four or five upcoming Saturdays

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

I'd like to create a dropdown in an html form that will dynamically list the next four upcoming Saturdays. The idea is that when someone is signing up they can choose which of the four upcoming Saturdays they'd like to come in to visit our space, so we can keep track and send automated email responses. The time is the same every week so that's not an issue.

Been trying to do this through Wordpress plugins but that's proving complicated to integrate with email software... I think it must be easier and cleaner to do it in html/javascript/php.

Comment: Hi! Welcome to SO! Please show what you've attempted and we can go from there.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: Welcome to SO.  I mean it, not like some others that use the phrase to mask their indifference.   I think your question is fine.  I really like your question.  It's a challenging question.

Comment: @mykaf Why?  It is not a simple problem.  Do you not understand the question well enough to not understand why the OP cannot provide their attempt?

Comment: @mplungjan There is nothing wrong with this question.  The problem may be your understanding of the difficulty of the question.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example

Note the generic nearestDay to get any day of the week from today until today next week

```js
const nearestDay = dayOfWeek => {
  let now = new Date();
  now.setDate(now.getDate() + (((dayOfWeek + 7 - now.getDay()) % 7) || 7));
  return now;
};

const dates = () => {
  let date = nearestDay(6); // Saturday
  const arr = [];
  while (arr.length < 4) {
    arr.push(date.toISOString().split("T")[0])
    date.setDate(date.getDate() + 7)
  }
  return arr;
}
const dateArr = dates();
document.getElementById("saturdays").innerHTML += dateArr.map(date => `<option value="${date}">${date}</option>`).join("");
```

```html
<select id="saturdays">
  <option value="">Please select</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?
echo '<label for="saturday">Choose which Saturday:</label>';
echo "<select id=\"saturday\" >\n";
$saturday = (6 - date('w',time())) ;  // how many days to Saturday 
$saturday = time() + ($saturday * 86400);   // number of seconds to Saturday
$value = date('Y-m-d',$saturday);  // Get proper form date format
$text = date('D M jS',$saturday);  // Get human readable format
echo "<option value=\"$option\">$text</option>\n";

for ($x = 1; $x < 4 ; $x++) {
  $saturday += 604800;
  $option =  date('m-d-y',$saturday) ;
  $text = date('D M jS',$saturday);
  echo "<option value=\"$option\">$text</option>:\n";
}
echo '</select>';
?>
```

[image: Saturday dropdown]

Comment: Stay DRY: https://onlinephp.io/c/30848

Comment: @mplungjan  I liked the way you added the implode.  That's the first time I have seen that method.

Answer (score 0):

Please check if below example can be used in your requirement.  I used a button so you can see what happens and you would probably use a different event such as onload for your application.

```js
function myFunction() {

  let dateToday = new Date();
  let dateCopy = new Date(dateToday.getTime());

  let mySelectID = document.getElementById("mySaturdays");


  for (let x = 1; x < 5; x++) {

    const nextSaturday = new Date(
      dateCopy.setDate(
        dateCopy.getDate() + ((7 - dateCopy.getDay() + 6) % 7 || 7),
      ),
    );

    let option = document.createElement("option");
    option.value = x;
    option.text = nextSaturday;
    mySelectID.add(option);
  }

}
```

```html
<form>
  <select id="mySaturdays" size="5">
  </select>
</form>
<br>

<button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Insert option</button>
```